# Get first and last enabled item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-directive, scope

I would like to get the first and last enabled item or where `disabled = false` from the object.

I have tried:

```
$scope.firstEnabled = function(obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        if(obj[i].disabled == false){
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2acwq3w/)**

This works fine for getting the first enabled item and i can do something similar to get the last.. However, my issue is that I would like to do both of those things in one iteration rather than 2 different functions and 2 different iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find **first enabled**

```
var first = false;
 if (!first) {
    $scope.firstEnabled = obj[i];
          first = true;
        };
```

To find **last enabled**, just assign in each iteration when disabled is false

```
$scope.lastEnabled = obj[i];
```

You can do like this

```
    var first = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      if (obj[i].disabled == false) {
        if (!first) {
          $scope.firstEnabled = obj[i];
          first = true
        };
        console.log(i);
        $scope.lastEnabled = obj[i];
      }
    }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NaghaveerGowda/2xvd97p4/3/)

Comment: Not correct... if i make any other item disabled=false.. it still says test3, test3

Comment: @user4756836 Sorry, I have updated my answer. Please have a look